# Checking for empty NSSet?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to check if a set is empty?

```
NSMutableSet *setEmpty = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

// Code to do things...

// Check for empty set?

[setEmpty release];
```

gary

Comment: This is a pretty simple task. You should get in the habit of looking at the docs for answers like these.

Comment: Hi Brad, I did check the docs, but missed the entry for count. More error on my part than rampant laziness.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [setEmpty count] to see how many elements are in the set... so:

```
if ([setEmpty count] == 0) {
```

or

```
if (![setEmpty count]) {
```

etc...

I didn't see an explicit 'isEmpty' method on http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html but if it exists, go for that instead of checking the count.

Comment: Thank you Malaxeur, perfect I looked for that both in the docs and in the Xcode auto-complete and missed it both times :( I don't think there is an 'isEmpty' as I got a missing method error when testing it. Anyways count is perfect, thank you for the answer and your time.

Comment: If you use it a lot, you could add an `isEmpty` method as a category on `NSSet`, which a body like `- (BOOL)isEmpty { return [self count] == 0; }`.

Answer (score 8):

What about this one for really big sets? The goal is to not do the count each time.

```
NSSet *mySet = ...

if ([mySet anyObject] == nil)
{
    // The set is empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> …here's the single-most used file in my shared repository:
>
> DMCommonMacros.h
>
> ```
> static inline BOOL IsEmpty(id thing) {
>     return thing == nil
>         || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
>         && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
>         || ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
>         && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
> }
> ```

—[Wil Shiply](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/2005/10/pimp-my-code-interlude-free-code.html)

This function will work on all Cocoa containers, strings, and NSData.